# How to actually stop an AppEngine form creating instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been trying to get an AppEngine project to simply stop running. After trying deleting versions, deleting instances, and even uploading straight up empty `main.py` and `worker.py` files the project is still using about 3 hours of instance hours per hour. I don't understand how this is physically possibly. Where are some places I can start looking, since where I've been looking before doesn't seem to have any relevance whatsoever.

Comment: I should add that this is not a production project. No one else should even know it exists, so no one else should be pulling up the URL and starting the instances.

Comment: Note that using more powerful [instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes) multiplies the instance hours usage (which are still reported in F1/B1 class units), see note at the end of [Standard environment instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing)

Comment: You should also check the app's request logs, that can give you hints about what brings up your instances and/or keeps them alive. Your `app.yaml` environment and scaling configs also matter, you may want to share them.

Comment: @DanCornilescu This particular project is in the free tier, and I don't know what instance class it is. I do know that it's billed at $0.05/hour.

Comment: Billing computations still happen for free tier projects, only the charges are waived if the usage is below some values. No bearing on the instances running. The instance class is configured in the `app.yaml` file via `instance_class`, if you don't have such configs the F1/B2 defaults are used, depending on having `automatic_scaling` configured or not.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be to disable (or even shutdown) your application. From [Google App Engine FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/):

> How can I disable one of my existing applications?
>
> - Disabling your application stops all serving requests, but your data and state are retained. You are still be billed for applicable
>     charges, such as Compute Engine instances. To release all the
>     resources used within the project, [shut down your project](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787).
>
> To disable your application:
>
> 1. In the GCP Console, go to the App Engine Settings page.
> 2. Click **Disable application** and follow the instructions.
> 3. Disabling your app takes effect immediately. Confirm that your application has been disabled by visiting the URL of your app, such as
>      `http://[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/`. Your application should
>      return an HTTP `404 Not Found` error.

Note that shutting the project down will be automatically followed by deletion in 30 days, so don't do that if you still want to re-enable the project at some point.

Comment: Disabling the AppEngine application sounds like exactly what I needed. I'm going to answer some of the comments I got before selecting this as the answer.

Comment: The one effect of this approach is that if you leave it shut down for too long it gets outright deleted, and if you start it again the documentation seems to indicate it will return to its previous state- which may be stuck in the endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the max instances in app.yaml:

```
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
```

Not sure if you can set that to `0`, but at least limit it to `1`.

Also

1) Make sure you don't have some backend instance (which uses its own app.yaml) running.

2) make sure you don't have any `cron` jobs running, or tasks stuck in the `taskqueue`

3) Try:

```
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

4) Shut down your instances.